# solutions to $X^T X +BX= C$

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to get a handle on solving the following matrix equation (for $X\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$):

$$X^T X + BX = C,$$

where $B, C\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$.

This form crops up in an implicit update rule I am working on. Any help for saying anything about the solution (conditions for uniqueness, existence, etc.) would be greatly appreciated! References to relevant papers or textbooks would be helpful too.

Comment: I would play with the quadratic formula for $n=1$ case and adapt it for a general $n$.

Comment: I have a feeling that both existence and uniqueness are hard to come by. For instance, if $B$ is the $0$-matrix, then $X^TX=C$, and so by taking determinants, I get $\det(X)^2=\det(C)$, meaning that $C$ must have a non-negative determinant. It's even true that $C$ is non-negative definite.

Comment: If you put $Y=X+\frac{B^T}2$ and split the equation into symmetric and skew-symmetric part, you get a system of two equations $Y^TY = \frac{BB^T}4 + \frac{C+C^T}2$ and $BY - (BY)^T = C-C^T$. The former one indicates that a necessary condition for the existence of a solution is that $\frac{BB^T}4+\frac{C+C^T}2$ is positive semidefinite. In the scalar case, this reduces to $B^2+4C\ge0$, which is the discriminant condition.

Comment: Very little can be said for such kinds of quadratic matrix equations. See [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/145225/how-to-solve-this-quadratic-matrix-equation) and [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.maths.manchester.ac.uk%2F~higham%2Fnarep%2Fnarep347.pdf&ei=lvLwVPTAG4qiyQTL9YH4Dw&usg=AFQjCNGnLggKymrO9dfOfDKpcELRRMEULQ&sig2=4qwA-bsdJxwh7ulruYkgXw)